# Concatenate arrays in Elixir

Tags: elixir

How do I concatenate arrays in Elixir?

If I have two arrays:

```
[1, 2]
```

and

```
[3, 4]
```

how do I concatenate them to be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can concatenate lists (not arrays) with the [++/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Kernel.html#++/2) function.

However often in functional programming you will build up a list using the cons (`|`) operator like so:

```
a = []              # []
b = ["foo" | a]     # ["foo"]         ["foo" | []]
c = ["bar" | b]     # ["bar", "foo"]  ["bar" | ["foo" | []]]
```

This is equivalent:

```
a = []              #  []
b = ["foo" | a]     #  ["foo" | []]
c = ["bar" | b]     #  ["bar" | ["foo" | []]]
```

You may well have seen this operator in pattern matching:

```
["bar" | tail] = ["bar", "foo"] #tail is now ["foo"]
```

You will often see lists built using this technique and then reversed at the end of the function call to get the results in the same order as using list concatenation (For example [Enum.filter/2](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4a0b64886dbcfbfea4965748cda4422367661c85/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L737)). This answer explains it well [Erlang: Can this be done without lists:reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179469/erlang-can-this-be-done-without-listsreverse/6179634#6179634)

You can read more about the list data type at http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#lists-or-tuples

Comment: Good point to make sure that the person who asked the question realizes that he (indefinite pronoun sense) is dealing with lists rather than arrays.

Comment: At the time of writing the question I did not understand this, but obviously now I do. Being that it's a fundamental part of Elixir, others are bound to ask the same question as I did. This answer addresses both the solution, and that it's not actually arrays that are being asked about.

Answer (score 25):

For concatenation, there is the `++` operator.

So for the example

```
iex> [1, 2] ++ [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Additionally, you can also remove parts of lists with `--`, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -- [3, 4, 5]` yields `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this within pipe operator use [[1, 2] |> Enum.concat([3, 4])](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#concat/2), or another variant [[1, 2] |> Kernel.++([3, 4])](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#++/2)